# "aged X" vs. "age X"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Should it be "aged 85" or "age 85", when you want to indicate someone's age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *aged*, such as in the following sentence:

> They have two children aged six and nine.

You could also use *aged* as in "volunteers aged between 25 and 40."

Notice that *aged* in phrases like *my aged aunt* or *the aged* means *very old*/*very old people*.

Comment: I think that's the predominant form, but I also think I've seen this done the other way on occasion.

Comment: I would say "They have two children, ages six and nine." instead of your example.  (I might put it in parentheses instead of using a comma.)  I don't know whether I'm prescriptively correct or not, but it sounds better to me than "aged".