# Person age 65 or Person aged 65

Tags: participial-adjectives

I came across this sentence on this [site](https://www.hhs.gov/immunization/who-and-when/adults/seniors/index.html).

> adults age 65 and older

I saw one thread related to this question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/aged-x-vs-age-x) but I will ask it here again.
Which one is correct?

1. A person age 65 and older
2. A person age**d** 65 and older

Comment: In a formal register - such as written text - number 2 should be used.  Otherwise one would need to say - *a person of age 65 and older*.

Comment: Thank you but this website hhs.gov is a U.S. government website and the phrase "adults age 65" appears several times on the same page the link of which I posted in my question. This made me wonder if this is just a typo.

Comment: It is not a big issue, and hence it is a frequent error. But see @gotube's answer below. I didn't spot the obvious fact that it should be "aged 65 **or** older".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are wrong.

If it's ***a*** person --meaning just one-- then that person cannot be more than one age at the same time, so "65 *and* older" makes no sense. Best would be:

> A person age**d** 65 **or** older

If it's about a group of people, then:

> **People** age**d** 65 **and** older

is also correct.

It's common enough to say, "people age 65 and older". This is a shortened version of the correct:

> "...people ***of*** age 65 and older..."

with the "of" omitted, but we understand it's there.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about it needing to be "or" rather than "and".

Answer (score -2):

‘Aged’ is the correct usage because it’s an age already attained my the person(s) being referred to.